# How to Sort a JTable's column when I'm entering in a JFrame?

Tags: java, sorting, jframe, jtable

I have a problem when I try to sort a `JTable`. If I press a column's header, I can sort the column easily. However, I want to automatically sort the first column of my `JTable` when the `JFrame` which contains the `JTable` is entered. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `SortKeys`. For example

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();

int columnIndexToSort = 0; //This is the first column
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnIndexToSort, SortOrder.ASCENDING));

sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
sorter.sort();
```

Have a look at [this website](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/6-techniques-for-sorting-jtable-you-should-know) and the [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/RowSorter.SortKey.html) for more information.